# CSS box-shadow in jQuery .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, box-shadow

Firefox 18 does not seem to recognize the `-moz-box-shadow` or the `box-shadow` CSS attribute.

If I use `border-color`, everything works fine.

```
$($this).hover(
    function () {
        //$(this).css('border-color', '#ff0');
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '10px', '10px', '5px', '#888');
        //$(this).css('-moz-box-shadow', '10px', '10px', '5px', '#888');
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('border-color', '');
        //$(this).css('border-width', '');
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.css` only takes **two** arguments, the property name and the value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to make the arguments into one string literal.  The value parameter of the `css(property name, value)` function is one argument.

```
 $(this).css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, the required fields must be in quotes, not the individual values.  Thanks, I am accepting your answer. Just have to wait till Stackoverflow lets me accept it :)

Comment: @Chris exactly, glad that helped.

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
$(this).css('box-shadow', '10px', '10px', '5px', '#888');
```

is an incorrect syntax. You need to have one value for the CSS property:

```
$(this).css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
```

Answer (score 4):

Needs to be:

```
$(this).hover(function() {
   $(this).css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
}, function() {
   $(this).css('border-color', '');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
$(this).css('-webkit-box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
$(this).css('-moz-box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
$(this).css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
```

Answer (score 2):

For Safari, Google Chrome and Opera use

```
$(this).css('-webkit-box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
```

For Mozilla Firefox use

```
$(this).css('-moz-box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
```

For other web browsers use

```
$(this).css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px #888');
```