# Using Javascript or JQuery for changing changing group of css attribute and properties

Tags: css

i just did take a look on same topics about this changing function .. 
But i didnt find sth about changing CSS attribute and properties in a time .. or also on google search , they were just one change ..

let me be more detailed

i have 1 design and it's coded right now in html,css,js and this design is in 1 or 2 more colors .. the thing is needed to be changes is COLOR (main) and COLOR of BoxShadow For example .. and all this are just colors need to be changed .. 2 DIV with Box Shadows and Body Background Color .. [each div has background color / color / box shodow color]

clearly i mean do sth / function to do group of properties for some IDs of css

[One more Question : Can i use a way to DO this in JS file and when its load it loaded and when clicked the function is the same .. here is a note ( how can i connect JS to CSS in separated files ? - OR they r Ok when loaded in HTML) ]

- if clicked on Link [EX] change color of back, content, title, designed
- [ Can i mix LESS function and javascript > if clicked load specific function in LESS and  that change the att and properties of an ID or CLASS ?? ]

Best Regards. Thanks

==============
Code is sth like this (HTML):

```
    <body>
    <div id="back">
        <div id="wrapp">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="title"><span>TEXT</span></div>
                <div id="count">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                      <input type="text" id="gig" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);">
                      <input type="button" id="btn" value ="Go" onclick="doClick();"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="result">
                    <script src="count.js"></script>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="designed">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

(CSS)

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
}
*:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #F2786C;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #F2786C;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #F2786C;
 transition: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}

::selection {color:#C73829;background:#f39c12;}
::-moz-selection {color:#C73829;background:#f39c12;}

#back {
 background: #e74c3c;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#wrapp {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo { 
 width: 100%;
 background: url(logo.png) center no-repeat;
 width: 100%; height: 128px;
 background-position: 230px;
 margin: 100px 0 0 0;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

#content {
 background: #DA4434;
 border-radius: 6px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 45px 0 0 0;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 2px #C73829;
}

#title {
 width: 100%;
 font-family:'Far.TwoLight',Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 color: #8A2626;
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#big { 
 font-size: 22px;
}

#count {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 margin: 40px 0 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 200px;
}

.wrapper1 {
  width: 100%;
}

#gig {
  background: #C73829;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 145px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8A2626;
}

#btn {
 background: #C73829;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 30px;
 font-family:,Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 color: #8A2626;
}

#result {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 font-family:Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 color: #8A2626;
}

#infos {
 background: #DA4434;
 border-radius: 6px;
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 2px #C73829;
 width: 100%;
 font-family:,Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #8A2626;
}

#designed { 
 background: #DA4434;
 border-radius: 6px;
 margin: 20px 200px;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 2px #C73829;
 width: 200px;
 font-family:Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 color: #8A2626;
}
```

Comment: Could you express your question more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this would be fairly simple.

There are two ways, one would be to

```
var styles = {
  backgroundColor : "#ddd",
  fontWeight: ""
};
$(".foo").css(styles);
```

Or for a more inline version:

```
$(".foo").css({backgroundColor: "#ddd", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" })
```

This is from the official jQuery documentation. (http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties)

Comment: Question : in console js it detects problem for att whick contain " - " between words like : box-shadow // the syntax in jquery is different ?

Comment: Found the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294721/css-box-shadow-in-jquery-css
Also : .css({ boxShadow: '1px 3px 6px #444' })